# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named keras

Tags: python, keras

**keras module is not found !**

First of all I install **Anaconda3-2019.03** and then I run

```
`conda install python=3.6.0`
```

Need to use python 3.6.0 version instead of Python 3.7.0
it shows an error,

```
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: failed
```

For ignoring this error then i follow another way and that's are below,

```
conda create --name py36 python=3.6
conda activate py36
```

It successfully  installed and then I install tensorflow and that's command is below,

```
pip install tensorflow
```

It also successfully installed and then I run keras in **jupyter notebook** but it show an error,

```
import keras
```

error below,

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-88d96843a926> in <module>
----> 1 import keras

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras'
```

**Note**: I try to solve this error, then I install keras using below command,

```
pip install keras
```

Now help me please for solving this problem.

Answer (score 1):

As of TensorFlow 2.0, one keras is available inside tensorflow, `from tensorflow import keras`

If you want to use original keras (although both have same working), `conda activate py36` then `python3.6 -m pip install keras` now you can do `import keras` in your code.

Comment: python3.6 -m pip install keras this command dosen't support , Please currect this command and kindly comment .

Comment: Hi @ImdadulHaque, are you on linux?

Comment: works in my case ```root@DESKTOP-M45OVJM:~# python3.6                                                                                       Python 3.6.9 (default, Jul 17 2020, 12:50:27)                                                                           [GCC 8.4.0] on linux                                                                                                    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.                                                  >>>   ```

Comment: Kindly type ```where python``` and post the results.

Comment: I am using windows operating system.

Comment: okay, can you try ```conda activate py36``` and then ```where python```

Comment: Do you want say, I should use the "python3.6 -m pip install keras" in IDLE? Please clear, I am confused.

Comment: What I suspect is keras is getting in some other ditribution of python

Comment: already i used "conda activate py36"  this command, please read the problem statement.

Comment: that's fine, trust me in this, now try 'where python'

Comment: It's ok brother. Thanks for your trying mood.